# How to query all children levels based on parent's ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web

I want to select all levels of children. I have this line of code:

```
Product = await _context.Product
          .Include(p => p.Image)
          .Include(o => o.Category)
          .Where(m => m.Category.ParentId == id).ToListAsync();
```

That works, but this way I get only the direct `child` of that `parent`.

How can I iterate all `Children` and show all the `Products` that have a common parent inspite of hierarchy level?

Here is the code of my `Category Model`:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }


}
```

Here is the code of my `Db Context`:

```
public class WebAppContext : DbContext
{
    public WebAppContext (DbContextOptions<WebAppContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(m => m.Children);
    }

    public DbSet<Image> Image { get; set; }
}
```